# Intellij IDEA 2020.1 ultimate: Unable to add certificate to bundle jre

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, java-11

I'm running into a strangeissue. I have this legacy multi module project and the "mvn clean package" is running successfully both from command line and using the intellij maven extension.
Anyway if I sync the project by using the same maven extension it fails and says that some dependency cannot be resolved and some maven plugin dependency too.....I cannot really understand what I did wrong and why syncing the project fails even if it builds and everything seems ok.
I'm on maven 3.6.3 (tried both my local instance and the bundled one with intellij idea)
jdk is 11 but the whole project is jdk 1.6 specified throught maven compiler plugin config (not my fault the java 1.6)

EDIT:
Forgot to mention. I have no compilation error, the error while doing sync on maven extension is "Could not transfer artifact xxx" from remote company artifactory repository (but it's working when doing mvn clean package from command line, and it's also in my local .m2 of course)

Here is the error I see when doing sync:

```
    Could not transfer artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02 from/to my.company.net (artifactory)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

But I already added my company certificat into  File | Settings | Tools | Server Certificates as reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220026)
And also to java cacert...

Even if I try specific plugin versions it doesn't work at all.

If I run the IDE by using a dedicated JDK (and add the certificate to it's cacert) it works....so basically I'm not able to add a certificate to the bundled jre

Comment: do you have compilation errors?

Comment: Actually not, the compilation goes well....when I sync the error I see is "Cannot find artifact" on the remote artifactory company repo...

Comment: what do you mean by syncing of project??

Comment: What are these artifacts? They're probably not required for building your project. Do you actually encounter a problem when building or running your application?

Comment: What are the artifacts? Please give the full error you get and full output from `mvn clean install` and how you declare this artifact in pom.xml.

Comment: Mvn clean install works as I said. Both from command line and intellij extension. Sync the project I mean the refresh button in the maven extension... So the project looks "red" even if it compiles

Comment: I already tried clearing the cache and so on, reloading the whole project and stuff like that, but nothing worked

Comment: Please answer my above questions and give more details. Thanks.

Comment: mvn clean install gives no error. Those artifacts are not part of my pom.xml (they are probably recursive dependencies, and it also happens with plugins dependencies)

Comment: I found the issue but not able to overcome it. It's about certificate and the bundle jre version of intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running the "Importing" with dedicated jdk.
Go to Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | BuildTools | Maven | Importing/Runner

I will try to figure out if removeing the certificate from java cacert and using the provided UI (File | Settings | Tools | Server Certificates) on Intellij will provide the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, just use the built-in IntelliJ-IDEA plugin for trusting custom certs:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-server-certificates.html